# How do I get the ID from the currently authenticated user in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How do I get the ID from the currently authenticated user in asp.net mvc

I asked this before
[How to tie SqlRoleProvider to "My" user table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426539/how-to-tie-sqlroleprovider-to-my-user-table)

And so now I am using this method to save the GUID from a new user into my table.

```
Guid id = MembershipService.GetUserID
```

So then I have that guid in my table as well as the built in authentication stuff.
What I need to do now is when someone gets authenticated is to get the ID as a guid of the currently logged in user.

Is this possible and if so how?

If there is an easier way please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at some of the other answers on the site:

[Your favorite "current user"-pattern for Asp.net applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286699/your-favorite-current-user-pattern-for-asp-net-applications/4287542#4287542)

[Should I use the username, or the user's ID to reference authenticated users in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911/asp-net-authentication-user-name-vs-user-id)

[Getting the GUID of the current user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769313/getting-the-guid-of-the-current-user)